# How do i insert data into field of one model, which is OnetoOneField mapped with another model

Tags: django, postgresql

These are my models where `eda_defect_id` of `eda_detail` is a one-to-one field referring the model `defect_details`.

```
class defect_details(models.Model):
    defect_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class eda_detail(models.Model):
    eda_defect_id = models.OneToOneField('defects.defect_details',primary_key=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    analysis_writeup = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

In my code i am trying to insert into models but getting the error:

```
from defects.models import defect_details
from edainfo.models import eda_detail

defect_id = "Jira-SMSV-512"
description = "Hello There"
defect_obj = defect_details(defect_id=defect_id, description=description)
defect_obj.save()

eda_obj = eda_detail(eda_defect_id=defect_id)
eda_obj.save()
```

> ERROR:
>   ValueError: Cannot assign "'Jira-SMSV-512'": "eda_detail.eda_defect_id" must be a "defect_details" instance.

Comment: Separate point, but don't give your relationship fields names ending in `_id`. The `eda_defect_id` field should just be called `eda_defect`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `eda_detail` model has OneToOne on the `defect_details` model, so while saving data, you can pass only instances of `defect_details` and not strings to eda_detail,

so your code should be like

```
eda_obj = eda_detail(eda_defect_id=defect_obj)
```

and then save this using `eda_obj.save()`

For an example from the django docs, [Django OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)